# should a domain model keep itself consistent using events?

Tags: domain-driven-design, domain-model

I am working on an application where we try to use a Domain Model. The idea is to keep the business logic inside the objects in the Domain Model. Now a lot is done by objects subscribing to related objects to react to changes in them. This is done through PropertyChanged and CollectionChanged. This work OK except in the following:

Complex actions : Where a lot of changes should be handled as a group (and not individual property/collection changes). Should I / how can I 'build' transactions?

Persistency : I use NHibernate for persistency and this also uses the public property setters of classes. When NHibernate hits the property a lot of bussiness logic is done (which seems unnecessary). Should I use custom setters for NHibernate?

Overal it seems that pushing all logic in the domain model makes the domain model rather complex. Any ideas???

Here's a 'sample' problem (sorry for the crappy tooling i use):

[image]

You can see the Project my container and objects below it are reacting to each other by subscribing. Now changes to Network are done via NetworkEditor but this editor has no knowledge of NetworkData. This data might even be defined in a another assembly sometimes. The flow goes from user->NetworkEditor->Network->NetworkData and the all other object interested. This does not seem to scale.

Answer (score 2):

I fear that combination of DDD and PropertyChanged/CollactionChanged events might now be the best idea. The problem is, that if you base your logic around these events it is extremely hard to manage the complexity as one PropertyChanged leads to another and another and soon enough you loose control.

Another reason why ProportyChanged events and DDD doesn't exactly fit is that in DDD every business operation should be as explicit as possible. Keep in mind that DDD is supposed to bring technical stuff into the world of business, not the other way around. And basing on the PropertyChanged/CollectionChanged doesn't seem very explicit.

In DDD the main goal is to keep consistency inside aggregate, in other words, you need to model the aggregate in such way, that whatever operation you invoke the aggregate is valid and consistent (if the operation succeeds of course).

If you build your model right that there's no need to worry about 'building' transaction - an operation on aggregate should be a transaction itself.

I don't know how your model looks like, but you might consider moving the responsibilities one level 'up' in the aggregate tree, quite possibly adding additional logical entities in the process, instead of relying on the PropertyChanged events.

Example:

Lets assume you have a collection of payments with statuses and whenever a payment changes, you want to recalculate the total balance of customer orders. Instead of subscribing changes to the payments collection and calling a method on customer when collection changes, you might do something like this:

```
    public class CustomerOrder
    {
        public List<Payment> Payments { get; }
        public Balance BalanceForOrder { get; }

        public void SetPaymentAsReceived(Guid paymentId)
        {
            Payments.First(p => p.PaymentId == paymentId).Status = PaymentStatus.Received;
            RecalculateBalance();
        }
    }
```

You might have noticed, that we recalculate the balance of single order and not the balance of entire customer - and in most cases that's ok as customer belongs to another aggregate and its balance can be simply queried when needed. That is exactly the part that shows this 'consistency only within aggregate' thingy - we don't care about any other aggregate at this point, we only deal with single order. If that's not ok for requirements, then the domain is modeled incorrectly.

My point is, that in DDD there's no single good model for every scenario - you have to understand how the business works to be successful.

If you take a look at the example above, you'll see that there is no need to 'build' the transaction - entire transaction is located in `SetPaymentAsReceived` method. In most cases, one user action should lead to one particular method on an entity withing aggregate - this method explicitly relates to business operation (of course this method may call other methods).

As for events in DDD, there is a concept of Domain Events, however these are not directly related with PropertyChanged/CollectionChanged technical events. Domain Events indicate the business operations (transactions) that have been completed by an aggregate.

> Overal it seems that pushing all logic in the domain model makes the
>   domain model rather complex

Of course it does as it is supposed to be used for scenarios with complex business logic. However if the domain is modeled correctly then it is easy to manage and control this complexity and that's one of the advantages of DDD.

Added after providing example:

Ok, and what about creating an aggregate root called Project - when you build aggregate root from Repository, you can fill it with NetworkData and the operation might look like this:

```
    public class Project
    {
        protected List<Network> networks;
        protected List<NetworkData> networkDatas;

        public void Mutate(string someKindOfNetworkId, object someParam)
        {
            var network = networks.First(n => n.Id == someKindOfNetworkId);
            var someResult = network.DoSomething(someParam);

            networkDatas.Where(d => d.NetworkId == someKindOfNetworkId)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(d => d.DoSomething(someResult, someParam));
        }
    }
```

NetworkEditor would not operate on Network directly, rather through Project using NetworkId.

Comment: Spot on. DDD entities can legitimately report property and collection changes, but only for outside observers like the presentation code- never for the purpose of domain logic.